# PHPで作成したページを取得するとContent-Lengthが出力されない

Tags: php

お世話になります。

WebサイトにPHPで作成したページを設置しています。
　そのページのレスポンスヘッダを取得したのですが、「Content-Length」が出力されていないようで少し困っています。
　なにかPHPの設定等で解決できるのでしょうか。
　ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: PHPというのは動的にHTMLを生成するわけですから、HTMLの中身(body全体)を出力し終わるまではContent-Lengthを決定することができません。従ってbodyより前に出力しなければいけないContent-LengthヘッダーはPHPでは出力されません。これは通常「PHPの設定等で解決」できるものではなく、コードの修正が必要になります。用途やサーバ構成によっては比較的簡単な修正で済む可能性もありますが、一体どのような目的で「Content-Length」が必要なのでしょうか?

Comment: お世話になります。
確かにそうですね。
それから、もう少しちゃんと調べてみたところ、HTTPレスポンスヘッダに「Transfer-Encoding=chunked」が入っているため、「Content-Length」は共存できないということがわかりました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「Transfer-Encodingがchunkedなら問題無い」と言うのであれば、無理にいじらない方が良いでしょうね。「問題無くは無い」という場合は、質問文を「編集」して必要な情報などを付け加えて下さい。

Comment: phpの出力制御 関数を使用すると、処理結果（htmlとか）を変数へ入れることが出来ます。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。ですが、今回は変更箇所が結構多くなりそうなのと、「Content-Length」を出力しなくても大丈夫そうなことが判明したので、変更は見送ろうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

( 間違った日本語を使ったことを許してください。 私はこの質問に答えるためにGoogle翻訳を使用しています。 )

Content-Lengthレスポンスを計算する最良の方法は、PHP出力バッファを使用することです。 私に例を挙げてみましょう：

```
<?php
    ob_start(); // あなたの出力をキャプチャし始める
    echo('有用な出力'."\n"); // いくつかの出力を追加する
    header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length()); // HTTPヘッダーを設定する
    ob_end_flush(); // あなたの出力を表示する
```

**これは、ファイルや画像を作成する場合にも有効です。**

これがあなたに役立つことを願っています !

Comment: I appreciate your advice.
In the script I currently create, I do not need to output the "Content - Length" header, so it seems to be OK, so I will leave it as it is.
If there are opportunities in the future, I would like to refer to your sample.
Thank you very much.
* I think my English is very bad, please forgive me.